# JavaScript: Node List to Array Conversion

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert Node List to Array. I want to print the list (`caption 1,...caption 5`), but it prints:

`[object HTMLLIElement],[object HTMLLIElement],[object HTMLLIElement],[object HTMLLIElement],[object HTMLLIElement],[object HTMLLIElement]`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Caption</title>
<style>
    .captn {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 200px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:serif, fantasy;
    font-size:36px;
    color: #009933;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


 <div> 
    <ul id = "caption" class="captn"><li id = "caption0">caption 0</li><li id = "caption1">caption 1</li><li id = "caption2">caption 2</li><li id = "caption3">caption 3</li><li id = "caption4">caption 4</li><li id = "caption5">caption 5</li></ul>
 </div> 

<script>

    var msg;
    var cap = [];
    var capList;

    var f = document.getElementsByClassName("captn");
    msg = f.item(0).childNodes;
    b = f.item(0).childNodes.length;
    var classAr = Array.prototype.slice.call(msg);

    document.write(classAr);


</script>       

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` and select all elements under class `captn` with an `id` beginning with `caption`, then convert the node list to array using`Array.from` and lastly `map` through the array, returning a new array containing only the `textContent`

```js
var captions = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.captn [id^="caption"]')
);

var captionsText = captions.map(function(caption) {
  return caption.textContent;
});


document.write(captionsText);
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="caption" class="captn">
    <li id="caption0">caption 0</li>
    <li id="caption1">caption 1</li>
    <li id="caption2">caption 2</li>
    <li id="caption3">caption 3</li>
    <li id="caption4">caption 4</li>
    <li id="caption5">caption 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new in Java Script. What is the meaning of Bitwise XOR operator in JavaScript: '.captn [id^="caption"]'

Comment: The hat symbol `^` in this context does not mean bitwise XOR.
`document.querySelectorAll` is a function which takes in a _selector_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll.
The `.captn` is a class selector and the `[id^="caption"]` is a attribute selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors.
The `^=` means starts with, so `[id^="caption"]` means select all the elements with an id that starts with "caption".
Please consider marking my answer with the green checkmark of it helped you!

Comment: Thanks again. This answer is a turning point in my understanding for JavaScript. I marked the top arrow in the answer, but I couldn't see the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
Array.from(nodeList)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to thank @Red Mercury that his answer greatly boosted my knowledge in JavaScript. I am new to Stack Overflow and don't know how to mark his answer green, if there is a gold mark, I would do for him. Thank you Red Mercury.

What I was trying to do is to put captions list as a sliding captions. It was easy to do with arrays in Javascript, but I was unable to convert node list into array, because nodelist did not work in loops with innerHtml. So here is the solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slide 3</title>
    <style>
       .captn {
    padding-top: 550px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:serif, fantasy;
    font-size:36px;
    color: #009933;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>


 <div> 
    <ul id = "caption" class="captn">
        <li id = "caption0">caption 0</li>
        <li id = "caption1">caption 1</li>
        <li id = "caption2">caption 2</li>
        <li id = "caption3">caption 3</li>
        <li id = "caption4">caption 4</li>
        <li id = "caption5">caption 5</li>
        <li id = "atim">item</li>
        <li id = "caption6">caption 6</li>
     </ul>
 </div> 

<script>
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var intv = 1000;
    var msg = "";
    var cap = [];
    var capList = "";


    var captions = Array.from(
            document.querySelectorAll('.captn [id ^= "caption"]')
        );

    var captionsText = captions.map(function(caption) {
            return caption.textContent;
        })


    for (i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
        cap[i] = captionsText[i] + "<br>";
        msg = cap[i];
        capList += msg.replace(/\,/g, "");
    }
    b = captions.length;

    function swapImage() {  
        var elm = document.getElementById("caption"); 
        elm.innerHTML = cap[j];

        if(j < b - 1 ) { 
            j++;
        }  
        else  { 
            j = 0; 
        }
        setTimeout("swapImage()", intv);
    }

    window.onload=swapImage;
    </script>   




</body>
</html>
```